# Create Multiple libraries [each for one package] from single src/main/java folder : GRADLE Project

Tags: gradle

There is a Gradle project as follows:

```
SampleProject
|
src
  |
   main
      |
      java
         |
         **abc**(pkg)
         |
         **xyz**(pkg)
```

Now, Build generates SampleProject.jar but I need to generate **abc.jar** and **xyz.jar** after project build.
Please suggest if any gradle scripts would solve this problem.

Comment: Please consider sharing the research you have already done. This lets people gauge what you know they can then tailor their answers better, ultimately helping you resolve your question faster.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend create a multi project Gradle with two module required for you.

See [Creating Multi-project Builds](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/)